# Latex Referencing A Separate PDF

Tags: latex, cross-reference

I am writing a long paper, and I would like to create a separate PDF for the appendices while still being able to reference appendix labels from my main document. Currently, my structure is

#### v12:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{appendixTables}
\begin{document}
\ref{reference1}
\ref{reference2}

....

\end{document}
```

#### appendixTables.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
....
\label{reference1}
\label{reference2}
...
\end{document}
```

An example of a reference in `appendixTables.tex` is the following:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\scriptsize 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccccccc} 
...
\end{tabular}} 
\caption{\textbf{A1-Covariates Balance Test between MS and NS in 50\% NS Cities (Subsequent Experiment)}}
\label{table.individualbetween.MS.and.NS.in.50...NS.Cities..Subsequent.Experiment.1.Exp3} 
\end{table}
```

The corresponding reference in `v12.tex` is

```
\ref{table.individualbetween.MS.and.NS.in.50...NS.Cities..Subsequent.Experiment.1.Exp3}
```

Now when I compile `V12.tex`, all of the places where references are cited from `appendixTables.tex` appear as `??`s. The result I want is to be able to create two separate PDFs (one for `v12.tex` and one for `appendixTables.tex`) while still have the correct reference numbers in `v12.tex`'s PDF. Please give me some pointers to fix this issue. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `appendixTables` is compiled before `v12`, this setup should work. Do you get any errors or warnings in your .log files?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but placing a tabular in a `\resizebox` is not a good idea. This will result in a suboptimal choice of font shape and inhomogeneous font size compared to the rest of your document. If your table does not fit, better reorganise it using a different layout or as last resort manually choose an appropriate font size.

Comment: @samcarter Yeah. I found out using "\resizebox" was exactly where the problem was. I ended up not using "\resizebox" to organize my tables, and everything worked just fine. I originally went with this style because I thought it was simple to just put tables in box formats and make the box fit whatever page size I wanted (no reformatting needed even if I change page size or margin size), but yeah you are right that it was probably not the best idea. Thank you!